# How do I update/change version of Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming. I have installed python 3.5.1 on my windows 10 64-bit machine. I have installed a few modules using pycharm. Since Python 3.5.2 has come out, should I update to 3.5.2? If yes how? Will my installed modules retain?

Comment: Yes.  But unless you have a reason to upgrade, it isn't necessary

Comment: How? The same way you installed 3.5.1... Go download the installer

Comment: On Windows, you will just have to download the new installer and install it.  You can either keep the other version, or remove it first.  As said by others, however, you don't need to upgrade unless you need one of the new features.  Especially when it comes to a minor release like that.  You will have to manually install the modules again into the new version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed `anaconda` than you can run this command:

```
conda update python
```

This will update your python to latest version.

Comment: Pip can update python? Since when?

Comment: @cricket_007 But we can update it with conda.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Python each time when it brings out new version isn't necessary, you shall look into https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-2 if there is some useful stuff for you do it, but as I said it isn't necessary.